# Alternative to Curl - Local file

Tags: php, post, curl, local

We've multiple virtual hosts / domains setup in our server. I need to POST data to a file (basically execute the php and get the results) in a VHost from a different VHost (read: same server, different v-hosts).

I am able to do this with `curl`. Like `curl http://vhost/file.php`. But I am wondering if there is a better way to do this without `curl`, to execute a local php file. Another issue is with vhosts. vhosts are not configured properly. So `localhost` instead of vhost is the only choice, so it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a "better" way? It works, and nothing actually goes out over the network, the traffic will bounce back up the network stack long before it hits the NIC. Unless you want to re-code these applications to deal with some strange new method of local invocation, I'd just leave it as it is.

Comment: @Sammitch Sorry I am newbie with network stuff. So are you saying, even if I use the public URL, something like `http://mydomain.com`, its going to hit the local server directly and not over the network?

Comment: That's correct. The only thing that will go out on the network is a DNS lookup for the hostname.

Comment: Thanks! I am good with curl then. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a "better" way? It works, and nothing actually goes out over the network, the traffic will bounce back up the network stack long before it hits the NIC. Unless you want to re-code these applications to deal with some strange new method of local invocation, I'd just leave it as it is.

The only thing that will actually go out over the network is a DNS request to resolve the hostname.

Answer (score 3):

`shell_exec()` will execute a local command and return a string.

`$output = shell_exec('php file.php');` should do what you want I think. You're going to have to pass in the domain name with an argument because the command line doesn't know any different.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need to do POST request. POST is a method of HTTP request, which is what curl is for. That being said I see nothing wrong with using CURL for your task.